# Get unique row (at the moment)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-concurrency

I have a high traffic PHP site (lots of concurrent visitors) that uses MySQL for persistence. The site can be used to purchase various gift cards.

The controller in PHP handles purchases like this:

###### Step 1

```
SELECT id, reference_number, card_number FROM cards WHERE category_id = 3 AND card_case = 'unused' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

+---------+------------------+------------------+
| id      | reference_number | card_number      |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
| 3324791 | 11556267335      | 0638570501       |
+---------+------------------+------------------+
```

###### Step 2

```
INSERT INTO orders (date_created, card_id, price, client_id) values ('2021-09-08 06:40:55', 3324791, 110.00, 7);
```

###### Step 3

```
UPDATE cards SET card_case = 'used' WHERE id = 3324791;
```

**The problem:**
When there are lots of visitors to the site, there can be multiple "simultaneous" purchases (at least, within the same second) for the same category of card. This means that different clients end up taking the same card. How can I change the query in Step 1 so that the row returned is unique, and not returned for other clients (so that there are no duplicate purchases for the same card id)?

Comment: Which concurrency mode are you using?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would suggest to use transactions and locks - `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` (and maybe `SKIP LOCKED`):

```sql
-- Begin transaction
START TRANSACTION;
-- Grab first non-locked unused card
SELECT * 
FROM cards 
WHERE category_id = 3 AND card_case = 'unused' 
ORDER BY id ASC 
LIMIT 1 
FOR UPDATE 
SKIP LOCKED;
-- Add the order
INSERT INTO orders 
  (date_created, card_id, price, client_id) 
values ('2021-09-08 06:40:55', 3324791, 110.00, 7);
-- Change card status so it won't get picked anymore
UPDATE cards SET card_case = 'used' WHERE id = 3324791;
-- Commit the changes
COMMIT;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

You can also add UNIQUE constraint to `orders.card_id` column for additional protection and possibly use a foreign key constraint there to make sure data is consistent.

You can also consider removing `card_case` column and simply join the `orders` table on `card_id = orders.id`. The unused cards are the ones where `order.id IS NULL`.

In really high throughput systems, where you can't afford to lock the records, you may want to pre-reserve the cards before the order is actually confirmed and periodically release them to the pool if the payment was not made.

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT id, reference_number, card_number
FROM cards
WHERE category_id = 3 AND card_case = 'unused'
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;
```

You want an index on `cards(category_id, card_case, id)`.  Do note that an index will have a slight impact on `insert` performance and on `updates` that affect the indexed columns.  However, the win on the `SELECT` probably balances all that out.